# Next.js images return 500 error in production

Tags: google-app-engine, next.js, app.yaml

I am deploying a Next.js app on GAE and none of the images in the public folder get served, they all return 500 with the following error after reviewing logs

```
EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/workspace/.next/cache/images/zUb0XWtfOUy8jJS-olwIcsJpEse7wovGYRmT3B79mCc=/0.1641776976898.S-2U16B+8WquUZAAJsKsf1k9FpDiuBJX2T6gFU5eXy4=.svg
```

Here is how my app.yaml file looks like:

```
---
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
runtime: nodejs16
```

I run next build to get a production build, however none of the images load. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like GAE (Google App Engine) [does not allow  for writing](https://serverfault.com/questions/1000057/how-to-write-an-image-in-app-engine), you can read them but its probably trying to perform some transcoding in the request, e.g: convert to svg

One potential way maybe to host the images in an external URL or use a host like `imgix` or `cloudinary`

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#domains